How to simplify the custom task command?
When I'm typesetting the answer to an exam paper, I'd like to us a fontawesome logo to mark the correct choice of the problems, so I type the following with the task package and fontawesome5 package
\begin{tasks}(2)
    \task The choice A
    \task[\faIcon{check-square}.] The choice B
    \addtocounter{task}{1}
    \task The choice C
    \task The choice D
\end{tasks}

It appears a little trouble, so I want to create a new command that can achieve the effect quickly
\def\true{\task[\faIcon{check-square}.]}

Then I used the true command and it returned me the following error
Undefined control sequence.
\true ->\task

I also tried using the hook
\AtBeginEnvironment{tasks}{\def\true{\task[\faIcon{check-square}.]}}

However, it doesn't work. So, how can I achieve this effect?
The complete MWE is the following
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tasks,fontawesome5}
\settasks{label=\Alph*.}
\begin{document}

\def\true{\task[\faIcon{check-square}.]}

\begin{tasks}(2)
    \task The choice A
    \task[\faIcon{check-square}.] The choice B
    \addtocounter{task}{1}
    \task The choice C
    \task The choice D
\end{tasks}

The simplified code I'd like is
\begin{verbatim}
    \begin{tasks}(2)
        \task The choice A
        \true The choice B
        \task The choice C
        \task The choice D
    \end{tasks}
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}



It cannot work, because the package uses the literal \task as a delimiter.

Sorry, but it cannot work without heavy surgery on the package code. The problem is that the package code uses the literal \task for splitting the input into items. So your \true command doesn't make a new item and chaos ensues.
The best I can offer is a syntax such as \task[\true], so you can define \true to your liking.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tasks,fontawesome5}
\settasks{label=\Alph*.}

\newcommand\true{%
  \addtocounter{task}{1}%
  \ifinstructor\makebox[0pt][r]{\faIcon{check-square} }\fi
  \thetask
}
\newif\ifinstructor % starts false

\begin{document}

\begin{tasks}(2)
    \task The choice A
    \task[\true] The choice B
    \task The choice C
    \task The choice D
\end{tasks}

\instructortrue

\begin{tasks}(2)
    \task The choice A
    \task[\true] The choice B
    \task The choice C
    \task The choice D
\end{tasks}

\end{document}

Of course you'd set \instructortrue at begin document if you want to print the solution keys. Here I use the same environment by way of example.

